# Understanding etymology of 'misgiving'

Tags: etymology

From etymonline:

> misgiving (n.)
>
> c.1600, "feeling of mistrust or sudden apprehension," from misgive "cause to feel doubt" (1510s), usually said of one's heart or mind,
> from mis- (1) + give in its Middle English sense of "suggest."

How does "mis+suggest" imply "feeling of mistrust or sudden apprehension," and "cause to feel doubt"?

Comment: autosuggestion!

Comment: Should we look into the M.E. dictionary for the word *suggest*, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

The etymonline entry for *mis* and *suggest* has the following:

> [mis-](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=mis-&allowed_in_frame=0) — prefix meaning "bad, wrong,"
>
> [suggest](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=suggest&allowed_in_frame=0) — 1520s, "place before another's mind; put forward a proposition"

To *misgive* could then be to place a wrong or bad proposition before another's mind. Extending this to "doubt" or "mistrust" seems appropriate and *misgiving* is simply the specific bad or wrong thought.

But this is just a guess. The history of language isn't overtly logical on the surface and the details contained in etymonline's entries are not enough to fully understand this.

The [entry for give](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=give&allowed_in_frame=0), by the way, doesn't even mention "suggest".